# How to check if object is within collection on Domain object?

Tags: grails, associations, grails-orm

In requests to my application i often get ids of the objects, which should be associated. However I have to perform a check to see if they are.

Example scenario:
Class A and B are associated:

```
A {
    static hasMany = [bs: B]
}
```

In my request I will get aid and bid.
What I usually do is:

```
def a = A.get(aid)
def b = a.bs.find {it.id == bid}
```

What would be a better way to make this check? From performance point of view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If B has a belongsTo = [ a : A ] defined in it, then you can do this:

```
def a = A.get(aid)
def b = B.find("from B as b where b.id=:id and b.a = :a", [id:bid, a:a])
if (b) {
   // b exists -- do something with it here
} else {
   // uh oh! b isn't within a
}
```

This won't do an iteration over all the sets elements like your code. Essentially, it's the same as erturne's solution, but this actually loads the object.

Comment: Thanks Todd. I'm trying to avoid two way associations wherever I can. This is mostly due to the fact it would be many-to-many in most cases, and I only need it one way. But in case of two way this seems like a good idea. It would probably be even faster to do a B.get(bid) and perform a check if b.idA == aid [it would be done without grabbing A until it's needed].

Comment: That's the beauty of grails, there's a dozen ways to do just about anything! My suggestion, go with the simplest, easiest to read code and only optimize it if you find it's actually creating a real performance issue. Using profiling tools can help find the real trouble spots, and optimized code normally isn't as easy to understand, so I only hit the areas that cause the most delays to keep my code more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination is to drop to HQL and use count() to see if it exists. There may be more elegant ways to achieve the same thing (perhaps using withCriteria) but my first crack at it looks like:

```
def result = A.executeQuery("select count(*) from A as a inner join a.bs as b where a.id=:aid and b.id=:bid", [aid: aid, bid: bid] )
def associated = result[0] > 0
```

I think that would be pretty efficient, although anytime you're looking at improving performance it's best to take measurements of different implementations so you can compare them for yourself. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. ;-)

EDIT: I think it's efficient because I've left the heavy lifting in the database rather than pulling data for instances of A and B across the network, creating instances in memory, or iterating over results.

Comment: I think I made the example a little bit too simple, and it made you think all I'm after is check whether it exists. I would like to get this object as well, find will return it. I'll modify the question now. Thanks for the answer though